FlutterFormBuilder: How can I validate on Blur/Foxus Exit?
Using Flutter FormBuilder, I want to validate a field when the user moves away from a specific Field (e.g. Tab, mouse click). I also want to validate on save in case some validation involves multiple fields
I'm fine trying to add the FocusNode.add and remove listeners as a custom control if no one has done it already
Cheers
